# Illustrator Exporting REALLY small 300 dpi PNGs

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export, png, resolution

I keep trying to export 300dpi PNGs from Illustrator, on a 1500x1500 px artboard, and they keep turning out really small and pixelated, not big, beautiful, and vector-like as usual! Help!

Comment: Why would it matter what the DPI is if you speficy that the image is 1500 px x 1500 px?

Comment: Are you sure you are using px? I don't see how you would have a 1500 square pixel image, save it and then look like that...

Comment: DPI only refers to printers and output devices. There are no "dots" in raster images, only pixels, so pixels per inch (ppi) is the image resolution measurement, not DPI. Your confusion about this might be part of your problem with understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Export, use "Save For Web" which lets you preview and specify the exact pixel dimensions to output.

If you want to base it on your art board then make sure that option is checked. Of course start with 300 DPI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also select the element and copy it to your clipboard. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Photoshop and choose new <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. From there change the width and height units from pixels to a unit of measurement. Alter the resolution to your liking. Click create then paste just paste your artwork to the new artboard.